# Multi Image Slider

Tags: javascript, slider

Apple's iMac page has an amazing slider on it.

It's your standard image slider, but it looks like it utilizes multiple images that appear at different times in a single slide.

Anyone have a link to a tutorial that explains how this was done? The effect has some serious wow factor.

Here's the link: http://www.apple.com/imac/

Comment: Did you try looking through the page source?

Comment: it uses [css 3 transition](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp) this crappy link is a good start

Comment: @Ibu Please don't link to w3schools.com . . .

Comment: @levy, rather than complain, provide a better link :)

Comment: The only thing I could gather from looking at the code is that they're using multiple images wrapped in <figure> tags, and they're using the prototype framework. No clue how they're timing the the images, but swap view.js may have something to do with it.

Comment: @Levi Morrison: What's wrong with w3schools?

Comment: @Ibu Just Google it. . .  w3schools frequently gives misleading or out-of-date information.

Answer (score 1):

**Notes on sliders:**

- **Use a plug-in system.**  There are many robust ones.  If you are using jQuery, I recommend the [cycle plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/).  It is extremely customizable.
- **The navigation circles at the bottom all use a sprite (means [one image.](http://images.apple.com/imac/images/simplenav20110426.png))**  They then use `background-position` to display the proper portion of the image at one time.
- **Use visual whitespace.**  One reason Apple's slider looks so good is because the elements aren't cramped.  They have lots of room to breathe.

**Notes on the previous/next images:**

- **Position an `<a>` on the side and have the actual contents wrapped in another tag.**  Apple used a `<b>` for this.  I'd probably use a `<span>`.  Use `opacity` to make it invisible.
- **The `<a>` tag needs to cover a large area.**  You probably want to have it be 100% of the containers height, and be wide enough for the mouse to find it.
- **The inner tag contains the text or image you will display.**  Apple wrote `next` for the text, but then uses a `background-image` and shifts the text off-screen with `text-indent`.
- **Make inner tag visible when you hover on the `<a>`.** Again, you'll use `opacity` for this.
- **Uses CSS3 transitions for the fade-in/fade-out.**  Do some Googling to learn more about them.
- **Use JavaScript to determine whether you should show the `<a>` at all.**  This comes built-in to many slideshow plug-ins.  If you are using jQuery, I recommend the [cycle plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/).

---

```
/*this will fade only the opacity property in .25 seconds for both in and out */
-webkit-transition: .25s opacity ease-out;
-moz-transition: .25s opacity ease-out;
transition: .25s opacity ease-out;
```

Comment: I think I'm missing something. There's no fade in or out at all on the slider. The multiple images that make up a slide are animated in individually.

Comment: @jeffrey As my post currently stands, it demonstrates only the functionality of the previous/next images.  When I get a moment, I'll update it to include other aspects of the overall thing.  Put your mouse on the sides of the slider, you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Oh, I see. I hadn't even noticed that, but it's pretty nice. I'm still trying to figure out the main slider though. The ability to transition multiple images on a single slide is pretty impressive.

Answer (score 1):

AnythingSlider is the closest thing I have found to apple's slider so far. It animates elements of each slide independently. Check out the FX demo.

http://proloser.github.com/AnythingSlider/demos.html